# Installation Error MATLAB 2014a on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, matlab

I'm unable to install MATLAB version 2014a on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. The installation always fails with the error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mathworks.professionalinstaller.Launcher
```

I've tried to install to the MATLAB software from the ISO itself, but still the error persists. I'm posting the entire history of commands that I'm using to install MATLAB

```
siddharth@Mephisto:/media/siddharth/MATHWORKS_R2014A$ sudo ./install -v -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0/
Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /media/siddharth/MATHWORKS_R2014A
->  ARCH                = glnxa64
->  DISPLAY             = :0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_12048/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_12048/bin/glnxa64

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_12048/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m   -splash:"/media/siddharth/MATHWORKS_R2014A/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_12048/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jar/ko_KR:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jar/ja_JP:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jar/zh_CN:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jarext/webservices:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jarext/webservices/ws_client_core:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jarext/webservices/mcr_dws_client:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jarext/guice:/tmp/mathworks_12048/java/jarext/axis2 com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/media/siddharth/MATHWORKS_R2014A" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_12048" 

Installing ...
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mathworks.professionalinstaller.Launcher
Finished
```

Comment: Any reasons why you are using the `javadir` option?

Comment: Yes. without specifying this MATLAB installer isn't able to detect where JRE is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own. Turn out that the ISO file from which I was trying to install MATLAB had a corrupted `java` binary. I fixed it by copying the JDK Java Binary to replace the corrupted binary and it worked.